# How to calculate a full spin of a player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game and I want to give a score if the player rotates 360 degrees from its current rotation position. For example, let's say the player's current z rotation is 25 in the inspector. If the player's z rotation becomes 385, that means it makes a full spin.

By the way, since the player moves continuously, the current z value changes continuously too.

Here is what I do but it did not work as I expected.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentZRotation;
    
    void Update()
    {
        currentZRotation = UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(gameObject.transform).z;

        Debug.Log("z rotation: " + currentZRotation);
        if(currentZRotation >= 360 || currentZRotation <= -360)
        {
            Debug.Log("You spinned");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `UnityEditor` is NOT for runtime code.  It is unclear why you are using `UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation` and why you are looking at the `z` component of the rotation.  `y` is the up axis in unity, and rotational angles (euler angles) can be retrieved from `localEulerAngles` of a transform.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned [`UnityEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html) is a namespace that is completely stripped of during the build process and is only available within the Unity editor itself!

Assuming a 2D game where you rotate around one single axis (Z) instead of actually checking rotations - which are [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) which is difficult to interpret and [euler angles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) might not behave as you expected - I would rather simply use vectors.

In particular compare your current [`transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html) vector to the one from one frame before using [`Vector2.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html)

```
// keeps the last frames right vector
private Vector2 _previousRight;

// keeps the already rotated angle
private float _angle;

private void Start()
{
    _previousRight = transform.right;
}

private void Update()
{
    // get this frame's right vector
    var currentRight = transform.right;

    // compare it to the previous frame's right vector and sum up the delta angle
    _angle += Vector2.SignedAngle(_previousRight, currentRight);

    // store the current right vector for the next frame to compare
    _previousRight = currentRight;

    // did the angle reach +/- 360 ?
    if (Mathf.Abs(_angle) >= 360f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Completed Full Spin!");

        // if _angle > 360 subtract 360
        // if _angle < -360 add 360
        _angle -= 360f * Mathf.Sign(_angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything worked perfectly. Could you please explained in detailed why you used transform.right?

Comment: @LandOwner it doesn't matter, it can be any 2D vector we know .. you could as well use `transform.up`. Any vector that is only in the X or Y axis and we get provided by the transform component (it's these two ^^)